# Accessing resources from URL in VueCLI

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli-3

When I attempt to query any resource from my VueCLI project (e.g. `localhost:8080/src/assets/image.jpg`), it just loads the `App.vue` without a `router-view` element. How can I set up my project so it allows access to some files (maybe just the ones in `/res`) from the URL?

For context, I receive the image name as a prop (e.g. `image.jpg`), then use a computed property to prefix it with the location of the assets. Then I use `v-bind:src` on an `img` element to render it.

Comment: you would just need relative path from where you are trying to access it, like `./../src/assets/<image name>`

Comment: Trying that just gives me a version of the App.vue without anything in the `<router-view>` element.